# how can i get age from this keyword?

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
const meDetails = {
    firstName: 'arman',
    lastName: 'soltani',
    birthday: 1991,
    hasDriverLicense: true,

    calcAge: function () {
        this.age = 2037 - this.birthday;
        return this.age;
    }
};

console.log(meDetails.age);
```

why the age is not defined??

Comment: Before you call `calcAge()`, that property is not defined.

Comment: That's also not how you calculate someone's age. If they were born in 1991, do you think they're currently in their mid-40s?

Answer (score 0):

the variable of named 'age' is not initialized before calling calcAge.

at first you should call calcAge to init meDetailes.age variable at runtime
then meDetails.age is valued and you can use it

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `calcAge()` first to set the `age` property

```
meDetails.calcAge();
console.log(meDetails.age);
```

But you probably want a [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) for `age`.

```js
const meDetails = {
    firstName: 'arman',
    lastName: 'soltani',
    birthday: 1991,
    hasDriverLicense: true,
    
    get age() {
      return 2037 - this.birthday;
    }
};

console.log(meDetails.age);
```